# Canvas UserControl DataContext update issue

Tags: wpf, canvas, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have developed a usercontrol, inside it has a canvas. I draw some lines and arcs in the canvas. Everytime when the datacontext changes, I need to force usercontrol's datacontext to null before updating new datacontext. Unless the new drawing is not getting updated. why is that? How to update Usercontrol's content (Actually canvas's content) without resetting the datacontext to null prior to update the new datacontext.

I use the following code. FlashControl is the usercontrol which contains canvas inside.

```
        (FlashControl.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = null;
        (FlashControl.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this.DataContext;
        FlashControl.DataContext = this.DataContext;
```

Update
::::::: This is my usercontrol

```
<UserControl x:Class="PricingRoutine.FlashGeneratorUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:PricingRoutine.Converters"
             xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:CustomFlashGenerator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Converters:TextPositionConverter x:Key="TextPositionConverter" />
        <Converters:LinetPositionConverter x:Key="LinePositionConverter" />
        <Converters:PointPositionConverter x:Key="PointPositionConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MajorGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path = CompositeObjectList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <!--<ViewBox Stretch="Uniform">-->
                    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ClipToBounds="False">
                        <Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin>
                            <Point X="0.5" Y="0.5" />
                        </Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin>

                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />                                           <!--Handle this one through binding-->
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />       <!--Handle this one through binding-->
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Line}">
                    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Line.X1>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LinePositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="X1">
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas"  Path="ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                                <Binding Path = "StartPoint.X" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.X1>
                        <Line.Y1>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LinePositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="Y1">
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas"  Path="ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                                <Binding Path = "StartPoint.Y" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.Y1>
                        <Line.X2>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LinePositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="X2">
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas"  Path="ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                                <Binding Path = "EndPoint.X" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.X2>
                        <Line.Y2>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LinePositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="Y2">
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas"  Path="ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding ElementName="MainCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                                <Binding Path = "EndPoint.Y" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.Y2>
                    </Line>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Did you try `FlashControl.InvalidateVisual()` or `FlashControl.InvalidateMeasure()`?

Comment: Or, if you are using code-behind to draw the lines and arcs in your `UserControl`, do you update the drawing when the `DataContextChanged` event of the `UserControl` fires?

Comment: @fmunkert, I have tried. Both didn't work and I dnt use codebehind to draw lines and arcs

Comment: could you post your xaml too, let's see if there is any binding issue?

Comment: @pushpraj, please check my usercontrol, it has simple lines only, I am wondering why do I need to reset to null

Comment: could you also show the code for `CompositeObjectList` property & `local:Line` class? seems like some notification issues.

Comment: @pushpraj, you are right, there is a notification issue inside CompositeObjectList. Thank you

Comment: Great find! you may write it as the answer and let others know how you solve the issue.